# std::ifstream::open error on eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to write a program that gives a table of temperature for each hour in one day with some starts that give an idea about the temperature. My problem is that eclipse (I use it on Mac OS) gives me "method 'open' can not be resolved". Would you please help me solving this problem?

And it would be so great if you have any suggestions in order to better the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{char temp[30];
cout<<"what is the name of the file you are using? ";
int rain[24],i,j,stars;
cin>>temp;
ifstream input;
input.open(temp);
if(input.fail())
{ cout<<"file did not open please check it\n";
system("pause");
return 1;
}
for(i=0;i<24;i++)
{input>>rain[i] ;
}

for(i=-30;i<=120;i+=30)
cout<<setw(10)<<right<<i;
cout<<endl;
for(i=0;i<24;i++)
{cout<<setw(10)<<left<<rain[i];
 if(rain[i]<0)
   {stars=(int)(abs(rain[i]) /3.);
    for(j=1;j<10-stars;j++)
         cout<<" ";
     for(j=0;j< stars;j++)  
          cout<<"*"; 
    cout<<"|\n";
   }
else
   {for(j=1;j<10;j++)
         cout<<" ";
     cout<<"|";
       stars=(int)(rain[i]/3.);  
     for(j=0;j<stars;j++)  
          cout<<"*"; 
    cout<<endl;
}
}
input.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

Open `Project explorer`, right click on your `project > Index > Rebuild`

Comment: Should be a comment, shouldn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Probably yes..! But this does worked for me in the past.. so why can't be an answer?

Comment: _'so why can't be an answer?'_ May be, may be not (that's why I didn't downvote as I usually would do for suspected comments). The question's to unclear ...

Comment: This answer did work for me.
Well,
there don't work for me.
input.open(temp);
if(input.fail())
input.close();